# Trouble with Arrays and Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am just starting java but I don't quite see what's wrong. I assume it has to do with my Array of Strings. When I run it, after the first input, I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at CurveBreaker.main(CurveBreaker.java:13)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurveBreaker {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of students.");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        int[] StudentGrades = new int[i];

        String[] Students = new String[i];

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student.");
        Students [i] = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the student's score.");
        StudentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
        String Best = Students [i];
        int BestNumb = StudentGrades [i];
        i--;
        for(i=i; i>0;i--){
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the student.");
            Students [i] = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the student's score.");
            StudentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
            if(StudentGrades[i] > BestNumb){
                BestNumb = StudentGrades[i];
                Best = Students [i];
            }

        }

        System.out.println("The highest score was " + BestNumb + " which was      achieved by " + Best);
    }
}
```

Comment: What values did you enter?

Comment: Check what this `for (i = i; i > 0; i--) {` is doing...

Comment: The error seems to be coming from `Students [i] = input.toString();`. This line does not make any sense. If someone entered `10`, the the greatest index you can use is `9`

Comment: Your title is completely useless. Please edit it to something that describes your issue.

Comment: Also, please use proper naming conventions. Start variable names with lower case like `studentGrades` and only Class names should start with capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays have indexes from `0` to `i-1`. You are trying to use `1` to `i`

Answer (score 1):

So, you prompt the user for the number of elements...

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of students.");
int i = input.nextInt();
int[] StudentGrades = new int[i];

String[] Students = new String[i];
```

Okay, that's cool, but then you do...

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the student.");
Students[i] = input.toString();
```

Now, there are two things wrong with this, one, `input.toString()` isn't going to ask the user for input, it's simply going to assign the results of `toString` to the Students array at element `i`

Two, `i` still equals the value that the user entered to start with. For example, if they enter `5`, you are trying to assign a value to element `5`, which doesn't exist, as Java arrays are `0` based (`0-4`)

A better solution might be to do something like...

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of students.");
int i = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // This is important, it clears the carriage return from the buffer
int[] StudentGrades = new int[i];
String[] Students = new String[i];

for (int index = 0; index < i; index++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the student.");
    Students[i] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the student's score.");
    StudentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    // calculate stuff here...
}
```

But, you seem to want to input them in reverse order, okay, use something like...

```
for (int index = i - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
```

instead...

You may also want to take a look at [The Arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)